# Getting an incomplete string from server with StreamReader C#

Tags: c#, server, request, streamreader

So I've been struggling with this thing for some time now but I am almost done. I send strings to a server in order to get a reply which is also a string. Reply from server looks like this:

> ......     ....8767853.....    .. .

I get just the number by filtering this string with RegEx. So the problem is that sometimes I receive an incomplete string like this:

> ......     ....87

And of course the number is wrong then. Sometimes I also get an empty string but I have a catch block for that. How can I go about the incomplete string?

Here's the code:

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;     
  
        public static void Request1(int start, int end)
                {
                    
        
                    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //отправление сообщения
                            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                            client.Connect(server, port);
                            NetworkStream streamSend = client.GetStream();
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamSend);
                            string request = i.ToString() + "\n";
                            writer.WriteLine(request);
                            writer.Flush();
        
                            //прием сообщения
                            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                            string message = reader.ReadLine();
        
        
                            //обрабатываем строку
                            string regex = message;
                            string pattern = @"\d+";
                            Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
                            MatchCollection match = rg.Matches(regex);
                            //Console.WriteLine(regex);
                            int result = Convert.ToInt32(match[0].Value);
                            Console.WriteLine("Number " + i + ": " + result);
                            numList[i] = result;
                            File.AppendAllText("File2.txt", "Number " + i + ": " + result + "\n");
                            
                            reader.Close();
                            writer.Close();
                            client.Close();
                        }
        
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error in number " + i + ". Retrying...");
                            i--;
        
                        }
        
                    }
```

Comment: Side note: you are missing a bunch of `using` statements here

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found a workaround for now. I just check the string for a complete number surrounded by either tabs or dots, if this condition is not met, I ask for this number again. I just changed a regex pattern a little bit:

```
  try
            {
                //отправление сообщения
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(server, port);
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, koi8);
                string request = i.ToString() + "\n";
                writer.WriteLine(request);
                writer.Flush();

                //прием сообщения
                
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, koi8);
                //Console.WriteLine(reader.CurrentEncoding);
                string message = reader.ReadLine();


                //обрабатываем строку
                string regex = message;
                string pattern = @"\W(\d+)\W";
                Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
                Match match = rg.Match(regex);
                Console.WriteLine(regex);
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + i + ": " + result);
                
                numList[i] = result;
                File.AppendAllText("File" + i + ".txt", "Number " + i + ": " + result + "\n" + message);

                
                reader.Close();
                writer.Close();
                client.Close();
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in number " + i + ". Retrying...");
                i--;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for LINQ here as opposed to a regular expression if your aim is as simple as extracting the numbers.

This will give you a few advantages, notably getting rid of the try-catch block, making your code look cleaner as well as getting rid of the unnecessary regex overhead.

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;
...
string message = "...... ....8767853..... .. ."
var messageDigitsArray = x.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
int result = Int.Parse(new string(messageDigitsArray));
```

Reference: [Char.IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit)

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion but at this point I am more worried about StreamReader giving me half of the received string. I'll think about implementing LINQ if I'd be able to get StreamReader work first.

Comment: So your issue is that the server sometimes returns an incomplete number? If so, are the numbers always 7 digits for example? In that case, keep a running total of digits and mark them as complete when you get 7.

Comment: I know what numbers I should receive exactly. That's the problem. I know what number I should get but sometimes it gets cut off a bit. So I'm figuring out why.